# EF LINQ include nested entities

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, linq

I have multi-leveled entities with the following hierarchy: 
Parent-> RootChildren -> Children -> Children -> .....

```
Class Parent 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual Child RootChildren {get; set;}
}    
Class Child
{
   public virtual List<Child> Children {get; set;}
}
```

Now, I want to include entity which include all the child as nested way.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
var parents = dbContext.Parent 
                    .Where(p => p.Id == id)
                    .Select(r => r.RootChildren)
                    .Include(c => c.Children)
                    .ToList();
```

It gives me result for first children but does not include all the nested children present in the tree.

Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Currently there is no out of the box way to eager load hierarchical data with unlimited nesting depth.

Comment: Was just typing an answer saying that EF Core has `ThenInclude(...)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, are you sure about that ? I have just tested it with EF6 and the records retrieved recursively.

Comment: @Rainman Here we are talking about eager loading (with single query). What you have tried is lazy loading (N + 1 queries).

Comment: No, I just performed eager loading with only one query. Even, I disabled lazy loading.

Comment: @Rainman Probably your test is incorrect. It works only if you retrieve the **whole** tree or the context is reused and the children entities are already there. I'm pretty sure about that - in both EF6 and EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to apply `Include` after `Select` and perform `Include` hierarchical;

```
var parents = dbContext.Parent
    .Where(p => p.Id == id)
    .Include(c => c.RootChildren.Children)
    .Select(r => r.RootChildren)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried but it did not worked. Eager Loading happens only for RootChildren but not for all the nested children.

Comment: Did you try with that ? ".Include(c => c.RootChildren.Children)"

Comment: Tried but same error

Comment: Are you using EF Core or EF 6 ? I have just tested it with EF6 and the data retrieving recursively. If you are using EF core, use ThenInclude() and actually I don't sure about the loading recursively.